# Override JSQMessagesInputToolbar in JSQMessagesViewController

Tags: objective-c, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

While button is pressed I'd like to show upon the existing JSQMessagesInputToolbar new view with timer and slider for cancellation.

One of the solution I found is overriding xib files but
all UI in the project is written in Objective C, so there is no xib files I could override.

Could you please advice alternative programmatic solution to implement it?

Thank you

Comment: I created the required view separately and then added the view on toolbar view

Comment: @Usama Sadiq Could you please add code example? Have you added it instead of the inputToolbar or just replaced its view?

Comment: Ok i am posting the code but that would not be complete you can guess the basic idea

Comment: @Usama Sadiq Thank you!

Comment: works like magic

Comment: Then bro kindly accept the answer , it will help others too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//MARK:- Input Toolbar Initialization
private func initRightToolBarView() -> Void {

    micButton = UIButton(frame: inputButtonFrame)
    micButton.setImage(CHAT_MIC_BUTTON,for:UIControlState())
    micButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(startRecording), for: .touchDown)
    micButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(endRecording), for: .touchUpInside)
    micButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cancelRecording), for: .touchDragExit)
    inputToolbar.contentView!.rightBarButtonContainerView!.addSubview(micButton)

    let timerLabelFrame = inputToolbar.contentView!.textView!.frame
    timerLabel = UILabel(frame: timerLabelFrame)
    timerLabel.text = "00:00"
    timerLabel.textAlignment = .center
    timerLabel.isHidden=true
    inputToolbar.contentView!.addSubview(timerLabel)

}
```

Now when the user starts recording then

```
    inputToolbar.contentView!.textView!.isHidden = true
    timerLabel.isHidden=false
```

when recording ends

```
    inputToolbar.contentView!.textView!.isHidden = false
    timerLabel.isHidden=true
```